# Use recursive CTE to find max value up until certain date

Tags: sql, sql-server, recursion, common-table-expression

Consider the following table (call it Table1):

```
ID      Date       Result
1    1/1/2020      10
2    1/2/2020      8
3    1/3/2020      12
4    1/4/2020      13
5    1/5/2020      9
6    1/6/2020      8.5
```

...
and so on.

How would you write, in one statement, a T-SQL command that returns the date and the MAX value of value of the Result column for all dates lesser or equal than the date in the Date column? In other words, the desired result output would be:

```
1/1/2020      10
1/2/2020      10
1/3/2020      12
1/4/2020      13
1/5/2020      13
1/6/2020      13
```

I was thinking a recursive CTE but I can't seem to figure out how to write.

Thank you in advance for your time and input.

Answer (score 1):

You wouldn't use a recursive CTE for this.  You would use window functions:

```
select t.*, max(result) over (order by date) as max_to_date
from t;
```